# The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HDWalletProvider on Polygon (matic) blockchain

Tags: events, web3-providers, block-header, polygon, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I use `wss://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com/v1/MY-APP-ID` as my polygon dApp provider, however I cannot subscribe on `newBlockHeaders` event with the following error:

```
Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HDWalletProvider
    at Timeout._onTimeout (...\node_modules\web3-core-subscriptions\lib\subscription.js:174:24)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) null
```

I've already seen [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84532/ethereum-error-provider-does-not-support-subscriptions-hdwalletprovider) link, but it does not make sense for my case (since I already use websocket RPC provider).

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue in HDWalletProvider in which you can attach a ws provider but it does not believe it allows event subscriptions. See [1](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2567#issuecomment-623530229).

Thanks to mikec on that issue page, the following workaround works:

```
const nodeIP = 'ws://192.168.1.xxx:xxxx';
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(nodeIP);
HDWalletProvider.prototype.on = wsProvider.on.bind(wsProvider);
let provider = new HDWalletProvider({privateKeys: [privateKey], providerOrUrl: wsProvider});
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

But, there is not yet any official solution.